# Wrong url in the response with OkHttp3

Tags: android, kotlin, networking, okhttp

I am executing two calls with OkHttp3. To two different urls, let's call them url1 and url2.

The calls something like this:

```
val request1 = Request.Builder()
    .url(url1)
    .build()

val result1 = okHttpClient.newCall(request1).await()

val request2 = Request.Builder()
    .url(url2)
    .build()

val result2 = okHttpClient.newCall(request2).await()
```

`await()` is just an extension that allows Call to run inside coroutines.

Now, when in the result 2 I get:

"Response{protocol=h2, code=404, message=, url=url1}"

and I can also see that:

```
networkResponse = "Response{protocol=h2, code=404, message=, url=url1}"
priorResponse = "Response{protocol=h2, code=302, message=, url=url2}"
```

Why is the networkResponse saying that it is from url1 ?

Comment: Yes, sorry, mistake in the question. I updated it

Comment: Is there a chance that url2 is redirecting with a 302 to url1?  If this is definitely not the case, I'd look at your implementation of await.

Comment: maybe you can use two okHttpClient not one

Comment: Show us the await function?

Comment: @JesseWilson sorry for the late reply. It is the await defined in this extension:
https://github.com/gildor/kotlin-coroutines-okhttp